Error when trying to use the command expo run:android
so I'm relatively novice to android dev so i need some advice.
Whenever I try to run expo prebuild and expo run:android, these error messages show:







I have also configured java_home (JDK 20) and android_home in system variable. any answer will be appreciated.
I hope to see the thing connect to my emulator.

don't post codes or error messages as screenshots

Ohhkaykay sorry
